# PowerPoint 2013 master page with image list selector

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm building a master page on PowerPoint.
I have a serie of small pictograms to put next to the title.
Instead of creating one master page by pictos, I'd like to know if there's a way to put an image selector that give choices between all the images you integrated inside the doc?

It could be either a "click and open" an image chooser in the correct directory, or a special selector with all the images integrated inside it.

Comment: nobody have any idea ?

Comment: So you don't want your master page to look the same each time you use it?